# Gray panel on images in Gallery?

Tags: android, image, gallery

Hey,
I have been trying to get a solution for this issue for a long time.

The issue is that the images in the Gallery get a gray transparent background, here is a picture of what I mean:

http://i51.tinypic.com/2hpnbja.png

The images are simply white images, though, as you can see in the picture above, they all get a gray background for some reason.

Can anyone tell me the source or how to fix this issue?

Here is the source folder (19 kb):
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18331007/GalleryDemo.rar

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's all about resources.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources> 
   <declare-styleable name="Gallery1"> 
      <attr name="android:galleryItemBackground"/> 
   </declare-styleable> 
</resources>
```

Try removing this declaration.

Comment: @Mighter       I've removed it but still have the same gray panel :(

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html try this.

Comment: @Mighter       Thats the source of my project, I dont know why I'm the only one having this issue... i discovered this bug after finishing most of the project so all the work for nothing :(

Comment: There is something missing in your Adapter class - when you create an ImageView you do not set it's background. Have a closer look.

Comment: @Mighter       Finally after 3 days looking for the solution, I found it.. it was those 3 lines: 

TypedArray a = c.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
        mGalleryItemBackground = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        a.recycle();